# Rails 3.2 Explains causing weird issues with document uploads

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is a weird issue that I couldn't find any mention of in Google.

I am *sometimes* encountering this exception within transactions that include a document upload to AWS S3.

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'app_name_development.begin' doesn't exist: EXPLAIN BEGIN
```

Turning off explains by commenting out this line in the environment config resolves the issue:

```
# config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

I'm running MySQL.

Comment: When rails things a database query has taken too long (which includes subqueries (from includes etc) then rails runs explain on all of the queries. It looks like somehow a transaction was run inside such a block, although from my reading of the source I can't explain how this would happen.

Comment: Right I understand why it's running the explains, but not why the explains are causing such a bizarre exception.

Comment: Presumably because ir's trying to explain the 'BEGIN' statement that marks the start of a transaction, which is invalid.. I don't quite see what would result in a begin statement being issued though

Comment: I've been having the exact same issue, and it appears to only happen with queries derived from squeel. Still investigating, but this might help you a bit.

Comment: Interesting and glad someone else is seeing this, but we're not using squeel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are running an older version of rails and it does not have the fixes for non-CRUD based explains: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7657

The problem is in activerecord itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a version of rails that still has the bug you can work around it by setting:

```
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = nil
```

in config/environments/development.rb.